# How to add image in live jquery search result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My code goes like this.

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(function () {
  var availableTags = [
    { value: "Sasaki to Miyano", File: '../sasaki-to-miyano.html' },
    { value: "One Piece", File: '../one-piece.html' },
    { value: "Kimetsu No Yaiba", File: '../Demon-Slayer.html' },
    { value: "Koe no Katachi", File: '../koe-no-katachi.html' },
    { value: "Spy x Family", File: '../watch-spy-x-family.html' }

  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.File);
      window.location.replace(ui.item.File)
    }
  });
});
```

the final resut is correct.. i just want to add image along with text..
how can i do that??

Demo: https://neverland-anime.ml/sasaki-to-miyano

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question is similar with this.

[jQuery UI - Formatting the autocomplete results. Add image possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070142/jquery-ui-formatting-the-autocomplete-results-add-image-possible)

check it out.